# Add a menu screen with libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm new at Java. I'm writing a simple game like Flappy Bird. I like the add menu screen before starting the game, like
-Start Game -Credits maybe options (maybe), something like that.

Here is my basic code for oncreate:

```
@Override
public void create () {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("background.png");
    smurf = new Texture("smurf.png");
    gargamel1 = new Texture("gargamel.png");
    gargamel2 = new Texture("gargamel.png");
    gargamel3 = new Texture("gargamel.png");
    distance = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
    random = new Random();

    smurfX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - smurf.getHeight() / 2;
    smurfY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3;

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    smurfCircle = new Circle();
    enemyCircles = new Circle[numberOfEnemies];
    enemyCircles2 = new Circle[numberOfEnemies];
    enemyCircles3 = new Circle[numberOfEnemies];

    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    font.getData().setScale(5);

    font2 = new BitmapFont();
    font2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    font2.getData().setScale(8);

    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfEnemies; i++){

        enemyOffSet[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
        enemyOffSet2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
        enemyOffSet3[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);

        enemyX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - gargamel1.getWidth() / 2 + i * distance;

        enemyCircles[i] = new Circle();
        enemyCircles2[i] = new Circle();
        enemyCircles3[i] = new Circle();
        sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("lose.ogg"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the [libGDX tutorial in the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game)? Chapter 2 is for you: "In this tutorial we will be extending the simple game "Drop", made in a previous tutorial. We will be adding a menu screen, and a couple of features to make this game a little more fully featured."

Answer (score 0):

To have several Screens you must extend `Game` in your Main class.
Default when you create a libGdx project with the "gdx-setup.jar" the Main class extends `ApplicationAdapter`.

```
public class MultipleScreen extends Game {
```

Now you have a method: `setScreen(Screen)`. With this method you can change Screens.

Here is a template which I use often for my projects. It also dispose the old screen:

```
public class MultipleScreen extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create () {

    }

    public void changeScreen(Screen newScreen){
        Screen oldScreen = getScreen();
        setScreen(newScreen);
        //Dispose the old screen to release resources
        if(oldScreen != null)
            oldScreen.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        //Clear the Screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Render the current Screen
        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        //Dispose Assets which you used in the whole Game
    }
}
```

Here I created a new method: `changeScreen(Screen)`. This method uses the `setScreen` method of the `Game` to set the screen and additional dispose the old one.

Now to make an example we need two Screens:

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

    //We need MultipleScreen class to change the screen
    private MultipleScreen game;

    public MenuScreen(MultipleScreen game) {
       this.game = game; 
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
    private float f = 0;
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //A simple Timer which changes the screen after 10 seconds
        f += delta;
        if(f > 10000){
            //Here you can add for example also the Level to the GameScreen which level the player choose
            //game.changeScreen(new GameScreen(game, levelNumber));
            game.changeScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And a GameScreen which simple displays the badlogic image:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private MultipleScreen game;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture img;

    public GameScreen(MultipleScreen game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //Here we don't need to add Gdx.gl.glClear...
        //because we already have this in our MultipleScreen which does this for every subScreen

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        //This things will be disposed if we change to another Screen to save resources
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
```

Now the last thing we must do is to set a Screen if our game Starts. So in the `create()` method of our Main class (in this case MultipleScreen) we add:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    changeScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
}
```

Now if the game is over we will go back to MenuScreen. But instead of creating a new MenuScreen everyTime we can add a `backToMenu()` method in our Main class:

```
private MenuScreen menuScreen;

@Override
public void create () {
    menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);
    backToMenu();
}

public void backToMenu(){
    setScreen(menuScreen);
}
```

In our GameScreen we now can simple call: `game.backToMenu();` to change back to MenuScreen without creating a new one.

**Important**
If we call `setScreen()` the `show()` method will be called and not the Constructor of the class.
So every Asset you dispose in the classes dispose() method you must create in the show() method not in the Constructor else you will have no Assets if you show a Screen a second time.

A hope this little guide will help you.
If you need more help you can find some tutorials in the Internet where they change Screen:

https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-project-setup/

Comment: I already finish my game. But i can't add render codes here. Because its too long. How can i add render codes here so you can help me easily

Comment: @Volker Ask a new question or make a GitHub repository or use some other Codeshare site

Comment: https://github.com/OguzhanAygun35/Question/blob/master/Libgdxgame here is my all codes

Comment: should i add new class like you said or just write in render section like TheChubbyPanda said?

Comment: @Volker I will do it with classes. It's clearer, you can add something easier and you work object-oriented which is the basic of java development